# Issue to export design images

Tags: kentico

I'm building my kentico website. Some pictures don't appear on live server. The image's folder has been created in to CMS/mysitename/Design/Images locally.

It's working fine locally. I have exported from localhost and imported to azure server. Everything is fine except theses images under Design folder.

How can I export it ??? Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the images are just part of the file system, rather than in your Kentico media library.  You should be able to FTP the folder up to Azure: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2014/08/01/microsoft-azure-web-site-connect-to-your-site-via-ftp-and-uploaddownload-files/

For future work, you could look into using the Kentio media library: https://docs.kentico.com/k11/managing-website-content/configuring-the-environment-for-content-editors/configuring-media-libraries

Comment: Thank you. I will try it and get back to you for the feedback.